# Magento downloader error permissions

Tags: magento

You can found my error image here:
http://kickbike.com/extra-net/error.tiff

I could not find similar issue.
I'm hosting locally this site. I try to put more permissions to folder /app, but there is error also and I can't do it.

What can cause this?

Comment: Use `chmod` commands to change permission of `/app` folder (and subfolders) to 777 in Terminal

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link to make proper file permissions as suggested by Varien.
Or,
During you local testing/enviroment, use 777 permissions to all folders and change to the preferred permissions once you put it in the server.

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/install-privs-after
```

to enable 777 access, do

```
sudo chmod 777 -R MAGENTO-INSTALLATION-FOLDER
```